# MongoDB: compare two output and merge to one

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections:

- history

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"1"},"name":"Josh","attachment":{"salary":"110","give":null}},
{"_id":{"$oid":"2"},"name":"Josh","attachment":{"salary":"110","give":1615988342517}}
```

- salary

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"1"},"salary":"110","history":["1","2"]}
```

I would like to implement to salary the history collection so i use aggregate:

```
[
  {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$history'
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'history', 
      'let': {
        'history_id': '$history'
      }, 
      'pipeline': [
        {
          '$addFields': {
            'Type': {
              '$toString': '$_id'
            }
          }
        }, {
          '$match': {
            '$expr': {
              '$eq': [
                '$Type', '$$history_id'
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ], 
      'as': 'getSalary'
    }
  }
]
```

but my problem is that i get two output not one, because of unwind the history field
so now with this aggregation the result is :

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"1"},"salary":"110","history":["1","2"],"getSalary": [{"_id":{"$oid":"1"},"name":"Josh","attachment":{"salary":"110","give":null}}}]}
AND
{"_id":{"$oid":"1"},"salary":"110","history":["1","2"],"getSalary": [{"_id":{"$oid":"2"},"name":"Josh","attachment":{"salary":"110","give":1615988342517}}}]}
```

i would like to achieve this result:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"1"},
"salary":"110",
"history":["1","2"],
"getSalary": [
{"_id":{"$oid":"1"},"name":"Josh","attachment":[{"salary":"110","give":null},{"salary":"110","give":1615988342517}]
]}
```

So if the salary _id is the same i would like if the getSalary contain all of the result from history collection

Any help would appreciate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use $project,$group and then $addToSet after $lookup like this:

```
[
  {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$history'
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'history', 
      'let': {
        'history_id': '$history'
      }, 
      'pipeline': [
        {
          '$addFields': {
            'Type': {
              '$toString': '$_id'
            }
          }
        }, {
          '$match': {
            '$expr': {
              '$eq': [
                '$Type', '$$history_id'
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ], 
      'as': 'getSalary'
    }
  },
{"$project": 
 {
  "_id":"$_id",
  "salary":"$salary",
  "history":"$history",
  "getSalary":"$getSalary"
 }
},
{"$group" : {
    "_id" : "$_id",
    "salary": { "$first": "$salary" },
    "history": { "$first": "$history" },
    "getSalary" : {
        "$addToSet" : {
            "_id" : "$getSalary._id",
            "name":"$getSalary.name",
            "attachment":"$getSalary.attachment"
        }
    }
   }
  }
 ]
```

Comment: hey thank you for the comment, the result is almost what i search, but now the getSalary is an array that contain object (which number is depend on how many history is) the object contain the attachment which contain an object which contain the first and second output. It's a bit messy because of this lot of nested doc
Is there a solution where the getSalaray is contain just the attachment and inside in the two expected output ?

Comment: Of course, sorry it was my mistake i write badly above:
"getSalary": [
{"_id":{"$oid":"1"},"name":"Josh","attachment":[{"salary":"110","give":null},{"salary":"110","give":1615988342517}]
]
```

Comment: Oh goted .. you want attachment inside one array.

Comment: yes exactly! is there a solution for this ?

Comment: Okay Let me figure out the way. Mark the above solution correct please.

Comment: Why aren't you storing userId in the history collection . I mean if you are storing userId along with name in the history collection. Then we can use another group on the basis of userId  and get the exact result you need.